# Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly (after restoring project)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When i'm trying to setup my realtime database in firebase after deleting and then restoring a project I get this error:

[image]

Anybody know why and how to fix it? :-)

Comment: I don't know where I could spell it wrong. I restored the project and with the same name (i don't know if you can choose another) and the Authentication is saved and working but i'm getting this message if I want to set up the real time database again.

Comment: This sounds weird. Please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Okay, I have just send them a request. Yes I think it is super wiered :-S

Comment: @MaikenMadsen did you figure out what was the issue?

Comment: @MaikenMadsen did you solve this issue.

Comment: I had deleted the firebase project on the console, but somehow firebase still showed it there, hence showing the error. Reloading the entire firebase console website worked for me

Answer (score 2):

This happens when immediately after restoring the project and you're trying to refresh and see if the project works again as expected. Give it sometime about 15-20 minutes and it'll work again. Further error I advice one to contact Firebase Support for they will answer in a period of 1-2 business days.